# Django How to save and retrieve survey state in database

Tags: django, django-forms

How can I save and retrieve a django form state to database?

Users are filling in a lengthy survey and want to save the survey state in between.

My ideas were:

Option 1. Saving request.POST to database (doesn't work), and then:

```
SurveyForm(my_saved_form_state or request.POST)
```

Option 2. Saving cleaned_data to database (does work) and then:

```
SurveyForm(my_saved_form_state or request.POST or None)
```

but the cleaned_data doesn't instantiate the form! Only the full request.POST (a QueryDict) seems to do that. How to proceed?

Comment: You can initialize a form with data with SurveyForm(initial={}) where initial is a dictionary with your values.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it, finally.

1. Saving the POST data to database:

   ```
   postdata = {}
   for key in request.POST.iterkeys():
       if len(request.POST.getlist(key)) > 1:
           postdata[key] = request.POST.getlist(key)  # for checkboxes
       else:
           postdata[key] = request.POST.get(key, u'')  # for all others
   person.saved_answers = postdata
   person.save()
   ```
2. Loading it from database:

   ```
       saved_answers = ast.literal_eval(person.saved_answers)  # convert unicode string into python object
       SurveyForm(saved_answers)
   ```